# Python. Как редактировать текст слоя в psd файле?

Tags: python

Ситуация в следующем:

Через телеграм бота получаем текст, который нужно добавить на фото. Проблема в том, что на фото этот текст находится под углом и немного размытый

Пробовал библиотеку **psd_tools**, но прочитав документацию, насколько я понял, редактировать слои с его помощью нельзя, только получать данные.

Есть ли возможность редактировать отдельные слои, возможно через **pillow** или любым другим способом?

Comment: Насколько существенно в вопросе что `через телеграм бота получаем текст` ? В любом случае, чтобы Вам кто-то ответил следует как минимум добавить изображение ожидаемого эффекта, а еще лучше приложить свои попытки — код. Все это Вы можете сделать через кнопку `Править` под вопросом

Comment: Я бы сделал svg с подложкой

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850899/editing-photoshop-psd-text-layers-programmatically